# HTTPS posts to HTTP URL's insecure?

Tags: security, http

Have to deal with some incorrectly assigned/redirected posts from an HTTPS server to HTTP URL's.  How much of a security risk are these?  Are they vulnerable to something like a man-in-the-middle attack?

Comment: What do you mean? If you're sending a POST over HTTPS, how could it suddenly transform into HTTP? Where is this HTTP transfer taking place? Do you have a form with a HTTP target URL?

Comment: BTW, a redirected `POST` ceases to be one - it'll come through as a `GET` without the form data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<form action="http://example.com/">` would post data insecurely, even if the page the `<form>` is on is itself HTTPS. Data sent in this manner can be intercepted / MITMed.

For the same reasons, `<form action="https://example.com/">` on a HTTP page is sent securely. However, the page the `<form>` is hosted on in this situation can itself be MITMed to inject malicious JavaScript or a changed `action` that could send the data elsewhere.

If you're working with sensitive data, both the page with the form and the form action **need** to be HTTPS.